# Why DDR3 RAS timing have to be greater than RCD + CAS timing?

Tags: memory, sdram, ddr

By definition, tRAS is the minimum delay from when a particular row in a bank is activated, to when it can be closed with a PRE command.

I have seen claims numerous times that tRAS should be > tRCD + tCAS . Also I've seen DDR parts recommend tRAS to be way over even this number. For example, in a DDR3 with 8-8-8-24. tRAS should be 24 while tRCD and tCAS are 8.

I agree tRAS comprises of the time it takes to select the Row (tRCD). But I've noticed in some examples that, the controller doesn't have to wait for the full-tCAS Latency before issuing a PRE. This is especially true in back-to-back transfers, here's a picture I borrowed (it shows only 1 READ transfer but is actually a part of a back-to-back READ):
[image: Notice PRE is issued before tCAS latency finishes]

So clearly from this diagram, the row need-not be active for the full tCAS. Then why does tRAS have to be greater than tRCD + tCAS?

My understanding is, it takes only tRTP (minimum read to pre delay) for a block of 8n bits to be latched into the FIFO buffer. After this, there is no need to keep the row active. Then why is tRAS supposed to be so high?

Comment: by definition, `RAS` is one of the command signals. Did you mean `tRAS` in your first 2 sentences? (I find the second sentence unclear too.) Understanding DDR datasheets requires some precision in language and thought! Also, a link to the full datasheet and (fig,page) reference could be useful.

Comment: Hello, yes I meant tRAS everywhere I mentioned RAS. But I thought the mention that RAS is the "delay" should have made it clear that is time I'm referring to. I will update the Question to reflect this. Is the question clear to you now?  The picture in question is borrowed from here: http://anandtech.com/show/3851/everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-about-sdram-memory-but-were-afraid-to-ask/5

Comment: Figure 6 on the above (anandtech.com) link.